# system verilog variables in extended class

Tags: inheritance, system-verilog

When I run below example, disp() function is displaying "value from class1". I am trying to understand
why is it not displaying "value from class2". Can anyone help me understand the concept here.

```
class class1;
    string reg_name = "value from class1";

    function new(string name="class1");
    endfunction

    function void disp();
        $display("disp: reg_name=%p", reg_name);
    endfunction
endclass                                                                                                                                                                

class class2 extends class1;
    string reg_name = "modified value"; 
    function new(string name="class2");
        reg_name = "value from class2";
    endfunction
endclass

program if_p;
    class2 c2;
    initial
    begin
        c2 = new();
        c2.disp();
    end
endprogram
```

Comment: Update: Actually it is working as expected if remove the declaration of reg_name in class2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the behavior of your example of displaying *"value from class1"* is because of two principles

1. When declaring variables in extended classes with the same name as a variable in a base class, you hide the base class variable from that extended class. If would have to reference `super.reg_name` from the extended class to access the base class variable.
2. With the exception of virtual methods, base classes have no knowledge of anything in extended classes. All references to `reg_name` from `class1` will be to the variable in `class1`

Even though the language allows it, a general rule is never to name variables with the same name in base and extended class. I've never seen a good reason to do this.

Comment: will it have any change in behavior if disp() is declared "virtual" ??

Comment: You have to both declare disp() virtual ***and*** override it in an extended class. This is a very basic principle of OOP and I suggest you look at some tutorials rather than asking one question at a time. http://go.mentor.com/SV-OOP